# Total Permutation of graph with $n$ vertex?

Tags: graph-theory

Given there are $n$ vertex. 
How to calculate total number of distinct graph having all $n$ vertex. 
Is there any formula for that?

Sorry one correction here:
There is one more rule that there should not be any circular (not finding the correct word) path.

example:
If there is one path
$v_1 \to v_2 \to v_3$
There should be no path from $v_1 \to v_3$ in the same graph.

Comment: Did you do any kind of search at all to see if this problem has been addressed? I think if you had - for example, if you had searched Google for anything like "number of distinct graphs with n vertices" you would have found a link to this: http://oeis.org/A000088.

Comment: @SteveKass Sorry I updated the question with more details. I think I have not explained problem correctly.

Comment: You want to count what are called "acyclic" graphs. If you had the additional condition that the graphs you count are connected, you are counting the number of non-isomorphic "trees" (trees are connected, acyclic graphs) with n vertices. There is a famous result due to Cayley (look up "Cayley's Formula") that gives the answer as $n^{n-2}$.   If you are not requiring that the graphs are connected, I don't know if it is a well-known result, but you can use Cayley's formula to help look for an answer.

Comment: @SteveKass The $n^{n-2}$ count is only correct for labeled trees.  For example, for $n=3$, there is only one unlabeled tree with 3 nodes (a path of length 3), but there are 3 ways you could label the central node, thus giving the count 3 for labeled trees.

Comment: @Ted: My bad. Yes, Cayley's formula is for labeled trees, so it doesn't help so much...

Comment: @SteveKass 
But for example If I have two vertex v1 and v2. According to formula total tree count will be 2^(2-2)=1. But there will be two tree one. 
v1->v2 having v1 is head and v2->v1 as head. Sorry if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there are $\dbinom{n}2$ possible edges. To construct a graph, between two vertices, you have the option to choose an edge or not choose an edge. Can you now work out how many graphs are possible?

**EDIT**

Answer to the new question. The number of trees on $n$ labelled vertices is $n^{n-2}$. In your case, since you do not enforce that your graph is connected (but there should be no cycle) the answer is
$$1+\sum_{k=2}^n \dbinom{n}k k^{k-2}$$ i.e. you choose $k$ vertices and have a tree within these $k$ vertices and letting $k$ run from $2$ to $n$ should give you the answer. You need to add $1$ since a graph with no edges also satisfies you criteria.

Comment: You will get every non-complete graph multiple times this way. For example, every graph you get by choosing only one of the possible edges will be the same.

Comment: @SteveKass I assume all the vertices/nodes are distinguishable.

Comment: Yes, for graphs with labeled vertices, your hint is a good one. (For what it's worth, "graph" is usually defined to have unlabeled vertices, though.)

Comment: @Marvis Sorry I updated the question with more details. I think I have not explained problem correctly.

Comment: Graphs are definitely not usually defined to have "unlabelled vertices". A graph is defined to be a set of vertices and a set edges such that.... The vertices are elements of a set and hence are distinct.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly see [Probability that an undirected graph has cycles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261701/probability-that-an-undirected-graph-has-cycles), the answer to your Q is there.

If the graph is labeled, it is the Cayley's formula. Otherwise an exponential solution on the same page.